# Quando é que uma oração não tem sujeito?

Tags: sintaxe, sujeito

Em quais casos uma oração não possui sujeito?

Um deles é quando o verbo `haver` indica existência:

> Haverá mudanças.

E os demais?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem três casos pertinentes aonde o sujeito não aparece na frase. São estes:

- O **sujeito subentendido**, também denominado de *sujeito nulo subentendido*, *sujeito desinencial*, *sujeito elíptico* ou *sujeito implícito*. Também era chamado há alguns anos atrás de *sujeito oculto*, mas tal denominação foi abolida.
- O **sujeito indeterminado**, também denomoniado de *sujeito nulo indeterminado*.
- O **sujeito inexistente**.

No **sujeito inexistente**, a oração simplesmente não possui nenhum tipo de sujeito, pois o verbo não se aplica a qualquer sujeito. É o que ocorre em caso de fenômenos naturais e coisas impessoais com relação à existência ou passagem de tempo, tais como:

- > Haverá mudanças.
- > Choveu ontem.
- > É meia-noite.

Isso é diferente do caso aonde o sujeito não aparece na frase, mas pode ser facilmente inferido, que é o caso do **sujeito subentendido**:

- > Comi arroz e feijão.
- > Teremos mudanças amanhã.
- > Fica o dia inteiro miando.

E há também o caso aonde o sujeito existe, mas não está presente na frase e nem especificado, este é o **sujeito indeterminado**:

- > Roubaram o banco.
- > Acharam que azul com laranja não ficou uma combinação legal.

Quando o sujeito não aparece na frase, uma forma de se descobrir se o sujeito é subentendido, indeterminado ou inexistente, é transformar a frase em uma pergunta:

- > Frase: **Comi arroz e feijão.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem comeu arroz e feijão?
  >   Resposta: Eu.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito subentendido**. O sujeito é "Eu", mas a palavra "Eu" não está na frase.
- > Frase: **Teremos mudanças amanhã.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem terá mudanças amanhã?
  >   Resposta: Nós.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito subentendido**. O sujeito é "Nós", mas a palavra "Nós" não está na frase.
- > Frase: **Fica o dia inteiro miando.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem fica o dia inteiro miando?
  >   Resposta: O gato.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito subentendido**. O sujeito é provavelmente um gato ou uma gata, embora não esteja expresso na frase.
- > Frase: **Roubaram o banco.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem roubou o banco?
  >   Resposta: Alguém, ou algum grupo de pessoas, ou não se sabe, ou isso só pode ser determinado olhando o contexto da frase no texto ou conversa na qual se encontra.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito indeterminado**, pois há um sujeito, mas não é possível saber-se qual analisando-se a frase isoladamente.
- > Frase: **Acharam que azul com laranja não ficou uma combinação legal.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem achou que azul com laranja não ficou uma combinação legal?
  >   Resposta: Alguém, ou algum grupo de pessoas, ou não se sabe, ou isso só pode ser determinado olhando o contexto da frase no texto ou conversa na qual se encontra.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito indeterminado**, pois há um sujeito, mas não é possível saber-se qual analisando-se a frase isoladamente.
- > Frase: **Haverá mudanças.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem haverá mudanças?
  >   Resposta: A pergunta posta dessa forma não tem sentido. Isso não se aplica a algo ou alguém.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito inexistente**. Trata-se de algo impessoal com relação a existência de algo (no caso as mudanças).
- > Frase: **Choveu ontem.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem choveu ontem?
  >   Resposta: A pergunta posta dessa forma não tem sentido. Isso não se aplica a algo ou alguém.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito inexistente**. Trata-se de um fenômeno meteorológico.
- > Frase: **É meia-noite.**
  >   Pergunta: Quem é meia-noite?
  >   Resposta: A pergunta posta dessa forma não tem sentido. Isso não se aplica a algo ou alguém.
  >   Conclusão: **Sujeito inexistente**. Trata-se de algo impessoal com relação a passagem do tempo.

Posto tudo isso, respondendo diretamete às suas perguntas:

> Quando uma oração não tem sujeito? [Título]
>   Em quais casos uma oração não possui sujeito? [Primeira frase do corpo da pergunta]

A resposta é que **apenas** no caso do sujeito inexistente, a oração não tem sujeito. Em todos os demais casos há algum sujeito.

No caso do sujeito subentendido e do sujeito indeterminado, ocorre que o sujeito existe, mas ele apenas não está expresso explicitamente na frase. E obviamente, nos casos do sujeito simples e composto, este está claramente expresso na frase e portanto existe.

Mais informações podem ser encontradas no [artigo na wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeito), em especial nas sessões de [sujeito inexistente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeito#Ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es_sem_sujeito,_sujeito_inexistente), [sujeito indeterminado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeito#Sujeito_indeterminado) e [sujeito oculto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeito#Sujeito_subentendido;_desinencial,_impl%C3%ADcito,_oculto_ou_el%C3%ADptico).

Outros links úteis:

- https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-subtipos-de-sujeito-nulo/32422
- http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/tipos-de-sujeito/
- http://www.profreis.com.br/tiposdesujeito.htm

Comment: @someonewithpc Só uma coisa acerca da sua edição: A afirmação de que "todas as orações têm sujeito" é falsa. O motivo é que no sujeito inexistente, de fato não há um sujeito na frase, equanto que nos demais casos há um sujeito na frase, embora este não apareça nela expresso.

Comment: Mas o fato de que se classifique como inexistente prova que existe :P

Comment: @someonewithpc Hã!? A palavra "inexistente" significa exatamente "não existe". Então como é que "inexistente prova que existe"?

Comment: Era uma piada...

Comment: Tem algumas referências que sustentam a resposta?

Comment: @E_net4 Acrescentei a wikipédia como referência.

Answer (score 2):

Além do exemplo já citado (verbo *haver* indicando existência), lembro-me dos casos (certamente existem outros):

- Quando o verbo é impessoal, por exemplo, os verbos que descrevem fenômenos naturais (*chover*, *nevar*, etc...): *Choveu muito.*.
- Quando o verbo indica tempo ou distância: *Faz (ou Há) muito tempo que eu não o vejo.*.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a gramática [[1](http://www.flip.pt/FLiP-On-line/Gramatica/Morfologia-Partes-do-discurso/Verbo/Elementos-do-verbo/Desinencias-pessoais.aspx),[2](http://www.oocities.org/fernandoflores.geo/sujeito.htm)], há três casos particulares onde o sujeito pode não existir ou não surgir explicitamente na oração:

1. Quando o verbo em si não se aplica a qualquer sujeito (só pode ser usado em alguns verbos, e é considerado assim um verbo [**impessoal**](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf55.php)):

> "Chove hoje."
>
> "Troveja."
>
> "Há sol."

2. Em casos onde não há identificação possível do sujeito, temos um **sujeito indeterminado**:

> "Batem à porta."
>
> "Chamam lá em cima."
>
> "Dizem que este ano haverá pouca chuva."

3. Há ainda o caso frequente do sujeito estar implicitamente presente e identificado pelo contexto, tendo então um **sujeito subentendido** (antigamente denomidado como **sujeito oculto** [[3](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/tipos-de-sujeito/)]):

> "Não consigo dormir." (o sujeito é necessariamente "eu")
>
> "O André é reguila. Está sempre a mexer-se." (o sujeito continua a ser o "André" na segunda frase)

Respondendo a pergunta à letra, só o primeiro caso é que contempla a não existência de sujeito.