# Como soa a omissão do pronome?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronomes

Estou aprendendo português no Duolingo. Eu sei que é permitido omitir o pronome onde o tempo verbal o torna inequívoco, por exemplo, dizer algo como 'estou aprendendo', mas isso soa preguiçoso, ou menos educado, na fala e na escrita normais?

Comment: [Similar](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/430/when-to-omit-personal-pronouns)

Comment: @DanGetz: Parece que, com base nas respostas, o português brasileiro é mais propenso a omitir a conjugação do verbo do que o pronome.

Comment: @SeanDuggan, a omissão da conjugação verbal é extremamente informal e é mais usada como gíria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não soa como preguiçoso! Inclusive, há um princípio comum a línguas de sujeito nulo como o português (especialmente o português europeu, dada a sua flexão mais rica em termos de pessoas, já que usa o "tu" e o paradigma de conjugação da segunda pessoa) chamado "evite o pronome". Este princípio nos diz que sempre que um falante de uma língua que permite sujeito nulo puder evitar o pronome, ele evitará (exceto quando isso causa ambigüidade, neste caso, o pronome não é omitido).

Portanto dizer apenas "estou cansado" é mais natural/comum do que com o pronome! A não ser que se queira dar ênfase em "eu".